# Infer route param name from path string, e.g. '/posts/:id'

Tags: typescript

I have a `Route` interface that contains a `params` object, and I want to get type safety on that params object, so that, e.g:

Given a route config:

```
{
  post: {
    path: 'posts/:id',
  }
}
```

```
navigtate({ name: 'post', params: { wrongKey: '1' } });
```

I'm using this interface for the `Route`, but `T[keyof T]` is clearly not able to infer *which* key it is.

```
type Route<T extends Config> = {
  hash?: string;
  name: keyof T & string;
  params?: RouteParams<T[keyof T]['path']>;
  search?: Record<string, string>;
};
```

I want this to error because `wrongKey` is not `id`. At the moment all I can do is get the param keys as types of `string`.

Full code in [playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgZQgcwLYQHbAM4A88SUEAHsDgCZ5R7ABOAltmgHxQC8sCipF1WgAMAJAG8WAMwgMoqTDmABBAL4B6cVJlz0WXACEVQgLAAoKFAD8PBnAwB5bABsQBeXuUcAPjyTvFhP4GbGYWAFw2do4uRLxsANxmZqCQkQ7OrkHA-JTYNHSMLOxcOgq4OYJQQmGa2NKy8LYYRlZpUBHYEABuMommyeDQAEoA9gCulI12hMR85Ln59MysHNxioVAA2gDSECBQLL4ougGxSGwAuhFLRX0qfQOpAMIjdUxoJevmWwDWe9eFVhXKBfCwWMC8AHLNAbFRme5JUwpYbjSgEAAqFTytBeb2Kaw2iDgeEQlihtw22DsEAifxAI0kUExADICtC%20uC4E08GSoKMJhAphhCOjNnSGUyLpsAOQQpDSi4JDZ4CBcgDGpIiQwgapGDCoBBurAANGyikrTAj%20qZddh6FAGKiILQCd8wCN6BExFA5YgItK1O76Hg1GEmFRpVAVMb4Q9TFSuu8EBAABSOgV4U3eqlYf1B4DS00Q7leqAAd0drF2IH9AEZIyoVABKeJQNRqKAEAC0XbkiHGTiopAYjtkACMdXAxiqqhXXmhq0IDrRsCNskJwyZrZIxtg1cAmK8oAmk2jMfNKrjJO82Cnbde0BF0ab05QtU6MWwmyCVEA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing `as const` to make your paths be literals and not just `string`:

```
const routes = {
  post: { path: '/posts/:id' },
  blah: { path: '/posts/:blah' },
} as const;
```

Second, your `navigate` needa a second generic parameter so your `parameters` is not inferred as a union of all possible parameters:

```
type Route<T extends Config, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  hash?: string;
  name: K;
  params?: RouteParams<T[K]['path']>;
  search?: Record<string, string>;
};

const routes = {
  post: { path: '/posts/:id' },
  blah: { path: '/posts/:blah' },
} as const;

navigate(routes, { name: 'post', params: { id: '1' } }); //  ok
navigate(routes, { name: 'post', params: {} }); //           errors: missing id
navigate(routes, { name: 'postj', params: { id: '1' } }); // errors: no postj
navigate(routes, { name: 'post', params: { idj: '1' } }); // errors: no idj

function navigate<T extends Config, K extends keyof T>(config: T, route: Route<T, K>) { }
```

https://tsplay.dev/NB8nbW

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [HOTScript library](https://github.com/gvergnaud/HOTScript). The last example (right before the `API` section) does something similar. You can do some edits to make it the way you like.

Or try to add `as const` behind the `routes` object, like this:

```
const routes = {
  post: { path: '/posts/:id' },
} as const;
```

This will type the `path` property as literal type, rather than just `string` type.

Comment: I know my `RouteParams` helper works correctly. I just need to be able to integrate it into the `Route` interface.

Comment: @AndyJessop Oh okay. I can see your playground link now. I updated my answer.